# How to find sum of numbers in a continuous manner in dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a column in my dataframe that contains numbers as following:

```
 0       0.150
 1       0.552
 2       0.144
 3       0.211
 4       1.228
    ...  
 1755    0.101
 1756    0.842
 1757    0.143
 1758    0.200
 1759    0.628
```

I want to find sum of 5 numbers continuously and then determine the highest result. For example, finding sum of first 5 numbers in the column (such as 0.150+0.552+0.144+0.211+1.228), then starting from the second number (0.552) finding sum of the next 5 numbers. I have tried to do this with **for** loop, but could not find appropriate algorithm to run.

Comment: You can use the built in Pandas functionality for rolling sum. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DataFrame.rolling` to determine the sum, and then calculate the maximum value of the result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})

# Calculate the rolling sum, then take maximum:
df['col1'].rolling(5).sum().max()
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want [`rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html), with a window size of `5`:

```
df.rolling(5).sum().max()
       
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4     1.228
1755  1.228
1756  1.228
1757  1.228
1758  1.228
1759  0.842
```

Comment: Wasn't the goal to first calculate the rolling sum, and only then find the maximum value? Or did I embarrassingly misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yes looks like your right, then it is `rolling().sum().max()` @liorr tahnks

Comment: Just noticed that that's what you've posted, hope you don't mind, but the change is *the* only way to get this right I think :) @liorr

Comment: Of course not, as long as we answered the question :)